# System Generator: How to configure the CORDIC divider block?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, floating-point, xilinx-system-generator, cordic

He all, I was wondering how should be the parameters fo the CORDIC divider block in order to get proper results.
In this example I´m trying to get 0.1/0.2 = 0.5 but I don´t get it and I don´t know why?
Please, does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you!!!

**EDIT:**
To take a look to the parameters of the CORDIC block see this question:
[System Generator: How to configure the CORDIC divider block. Understanding the block parameters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/system-generator-how-to-configure-the-cordic-divider-block-understanding-the-bl)

[image]

Comment: Does anyone create the tags 'System Generator' and 'cordic'?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the options available in the CORDIC divider block.

Comment: @tyblu: That´s done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latency on the cordic block, that looks as if you've chosen to use a single processing element - that will produce results of limited accuracy.  Very limited it appears :)

I tried using 10 elements for example, with [zeros (1,9) 1] for the "latency per processing element" - to get back to your 21 tick latency.  Making sure I ran the simulation long enough (oops), I then got a result (using UFixed_16_11 inputs) of 0.501953125.  Which is closer...

Does that help?

Comment: Yeeaah!!, I´ve put as 'Number of Proccessing Elements:' 10; and I´ve put a Latency for each Processing Element: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] and I´ve gotten 0.498.

Comment: Excellent! Just for future readers -  "[zeros (1,9) 1]" isn't (just) shorthand, you really can type that in the box.  Any legal matlab commands can go in the box and as long as they evaluate to a vector, it'll get used by the underlying scripts.