# System Generator: How to configure the CORDIC divider block. Understanding the block parameters

Tags: xilinx, floating-point, xilinx-system-generator, arithmetic-division, cordic

I have some dudes about the block parameters of the CORDIC DIVIDER.
**I would like to someone explain me the parameter called "Latency for each processing element".**
(See the parameters inside the red rectangle)

I don't understand the notation that is used, some zeros or ones between two brackets.

By the way, this question is realted with one I asked before: 
[System Generator: How to configure the CORDIC divider block?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/system-generator-how-to-configure-the-cordic-divider-block)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cordic block is split up into a bunch of processing elements (PEs).  Each PE is a bunch of logic operations.  There is some latency associated with each PE already.

You can add additional registers at any point in the pipeline by putting non-zero values into the vector you have highlighted.  The vector should have as many elements as you have requested PEs. In your case, you've requested one PE so it will only look at the first value of the vector, resulting in an additional latency of zero.

As regards notation - [] is standard Matlab for a vector (or matrix, depending on how it's used, but I'll not go into that here!). It's a bit like an array in other languages.

so

```
a=[5 6 7 8]
```

creates a 1x4 vector called `a`.  Element 1 (which you can access in matlab by doing `a(1)` ) has the value `5`.  Element 4 has the value `8`.

Note that Matlab starts its numbering from '1' not '0' like many other languages!

Comment: ok, I am understand the matlab notation of a vector, but for the cordic block, what means [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]? this represent a bunch of 11 PE?Other example...[1 1 1] This represents a bunch of 3 PE? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] represents the additional latencies of the 11PE if (and only if) you ask for 11 PEs.  You have to specify both parts correctly.